# How to stop quokka watching a file in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, quokka.js

I cannot stop quokka from executing a file. I'm using windows and vs code. The command from the documentation do not work. What is the command to stop quokka?

```
To start/restart Quokka on an existing file, use Cmd/Ctrl + K, Q.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Cmd/Ctrl + K, E instead to stop it, Q will keep restarting it

Update: If that doesn't work, press Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + P (Or go to View and click Command Palette), search Quokka for a list of all commands. One of those should be "Stop Current". Use that to stop Quokka on a particular file. There's also the "Stop All" option if you want to get rid of all Quokka instances.

Recommended action is to click the gear icon to the right on hover and set shortcuts for the commands you'd use most frequently. My "Stop Current" command is set to this by default I think - Cmd/Ctrl + K, E

Comment: it does not stop  the quokka